# Buying bitcoins in Zimbabwe

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I'd like to use US dollars to buy bitcoins in Zimbabwe. Does anyone know how I could do this or how to find bitcoin sellers in Zimbabwe?

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://localbitcoins.com/ it's a bitcoin escrow service, YMMV, read up up how it works [here](https://localbitcoins.com/guides/how-to-begin).
They list Harare as a place where you can trade with locals.
May be good for small amounts.

That or if you can open an bank account in Europe, USA, Australia etc (You can often do that from a large bank in your home country), wire the money to that account, then use one of the larger exchanges; like most other people do. However, that could be rather expensive with international wire & exchange fees etc. Better for larger amounts.